# Rails 5.2, Webpacker & Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, webpack

Can you specify which version of Angular to install via webpacker?

If you either create a new Rails (5.2.0) application:

```
*$ rails new myapp --webpack=angular*
```

Or add to an existing Rails application:

```
*$ bin/rails webpacker:install:angular*
```

Webpacker uses Angular 6.1.1. I want to port a Angular 4 app over then work on upgrading rather than hack away at to make it work on 6.

```
*$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "shine",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "bootstrap": "3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "ts-loader": "3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  }
}*
```

I've been through all the docs on Github and searched but I can't see a way to specify a version of angular.

Any suggestions are gratefully received.

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Update your package.json to specify `"@angular/common": "^4.4.0"` and the same version number for each `@angular` dependency. Then run `yarn install` to install the right, older versions you need.